# Мониторинг событий JS в браузере

Tags: javascript

Скажите, каким образом можно посмотреть, какие события с DCOM в данный момент выполняются в браузере (JS) на странице? Т.е. выполнение функций и так далее.

Например, нажимаю я по DIV, у которого `onclick="function();"`, а мне показывается, что происходит запуск `function()`.

Браузер Chrome, но есть и другие.

Comment: В Лисице запускаешь фаербаг выбираешь элемент пкм "Записывать события", и тебе будут отписывать все события на этом элементе

Comment: В опере (Dragonfly) тоже есть возможность увидеть какие события висят на элементе и поставить breakpoint на события DOM, HTML и прочих других событий...

Comment: вот например отслеживание события `click` в Dragonfly

![](http://4put.ru/pictures/max/398/1224198.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

- Открываем ***Chrome dev tools*** (F12)
- вкладка ***Sources***
- Справа спойлер ***Event Listener Breakpoints***
- Ставим галочку на событиях, которые нас интересуют
- profit :)

###### PS: если нужен скрин - пишите, но, как мне кажется, в нем нет необходимости, все предельно просто